# How to place a button on the left in TkInter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am doing a simple UI with TkInter in Python. I want a button at the top left, so I did something like

```py
    back = Button(explorer, text="Back")
    back.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
```

where `explorer` is a frame, and I expected to see the button on top left, but it's stuck in the center. Any suggestions? I already tried to add `side=TOP` but it didn't work. What's the right way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried `side='left'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your frame has to occupy all the horizontal space if you want to align its children. Something like (if you imported tkinter elements with `from tkinter import *`):

```
explorer.pack(fill=X)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, your parent frame should fill the x space.
This is an example of the parent frame not filling x:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

element = tk.Frame(root)
element.pack() # No fill

tk.Button(element, text='No Fill').pack(anchor='w')

# To show the fill
tk.Label(root, text='Fill X', bg='green').pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

And the result is the button is in the center despite the anchor:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAgmH.png

But, make this change:

```
element.pack(fill='x')
```

And now your button will be in the top left like here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoGGj.png

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter has 3 modules to set items:
.pack which puts everything more or less random
.grid where you can define the row and column
.place where you define everything in pixels

so you could use something like

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

button = Button(text = 'back')
button.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


root.mainloop()
```

This shows how to use the .grid function. Keep in mind that the size of each grid is defined by its largest content. If you have a long entry field , the column its placed in is going to be as wide as the entry.

you could also use the .place function, but this one requires the most work. For me its always guessing and rerunning until im happy with it.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

button = Button(text = 'back')

root.geometry("150x100")
button.place(x=30, y=30)


root.mainloop()
```

So in summary, use .pack if you dont care, .grid if you want some kind of control and .place if you want to be accurate. And keep in mind to use only ONE at a time.

Comment: I don't think "use .pack if you don't care" is good advice. That makes it sound like the behavior of  `pack` is indeterminate, which it isn't You can care very much where a widget goes and still use `pack`. Also, the language bout using only one is a bit imprecise - you can use all three in an app when you use them correctly and follow some basic rules.

Comment: guess your right, i just find it more pleasant to use .grid OR .place for understandability. For me it sets the widgets in relationship without having to think trough it everytime again. And maybe its just me, but i think of .pack as kinda messy so i dont use it all.

Comment: `pack` really shines when you need a purely horizontal or purely vertical layout, such as toolbar / main area / status bar layout, or sidebar / main area, or toolbar with a row of buttons. It's also arguably best if you're just adding a single child to a parent. `pack`, `place`, and `grid` all have strengths and weaknesses.